# 'body.append' slot not showing in Vuetify Data table component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When adding the 'body.append' slot to a data table, I expected the contents to be appended to the end of the body. However, it does not appear.

```
<v-data-table>
  <template slot="body">
    ...contents...
  </template>
  <template slot="body.append">
    ...appended contents...
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'body.append' slot cannot be used with the 'body' slot. You can append your content by moving it to the end of your 'body' slot template.